# Send Powershell results to email using SMTP

Tags: powershell, smtp, certificate

```
#Build the base pieces for emailing results 
$ServerName = gc env:computername 
$SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient 
$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
$MailMessage.Body = "" 



$SmtpClient.Host = "mail" 
$MailMessage.from = ($ServerName + "@company.com") 
$MailMessage.To.add("josh.o@comapany.com") 
$MailMessage.Subject = $ServerName + " Certificate Expiration Results" 

$threshold = 300   #Number of days to look for expiring certificates 
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)   #Set deadline date 
Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPeople | foreach { 
If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline) { $_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, 
@{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter -
(Get-Date)).Days}} } 


}
```

This script checks for certificate that will expire within the specified time frame specified, however I want to create a scheduled task and make it send me emails. I am currently stuck here. Does anyone have an idea on how to make this send me emails using the SMTP server? Thanks

Comment: Are you running V1?  If not, then you'd be doing yourself and everyone else a favor if you'd switch to Send-MailMessage.

Comment: Please how do I do that? I am not running V1 but v.3. Thanks

Comment: Start by running Get-Help Send-MailMessage -Full.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Mail-Output
{  
Param(
[String]$subject
)
$From = "EmailFrom@example.com"
$To = "EmailTo@example.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.example.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "Username"
$Password = "Password"
$body = "Body of email goes here"

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);

$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,   $Password);
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body);
}
```

This is what I use to send simple SMTP emails within Powershell. It basically is just Send-MailMessage expanded to show what the cmdlet actually does.